# Traveling through the Astral Plane

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, travel, astral, portals

I'm new to D&D and I don't understand all of its concepts, for example, Astral Plane.

From what I understand, you can travel there physically through a portal and travel to other planes this way. However, you can also use a spell like [Astral Projection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection). This spell transfers your consciousness to the Astral Plane and connects it to your physical body with a silver cord. Your body stays where it was  and if the cord is broken, you die.

What happens when this Astral form enters a portal to another plane?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## You enter the new plane whole

From the spell description:

> Your astral form can freely travel through the Astral Plane and can
> pass through portals there leading to any other plane. If you enter a
> new plane or return to the plane you were on when casting this spell,
> your body and possessions are transported along the silver cord,
> allowing you to re-enter your body as you enter the new plane. (PHB 215)

While the text uses "allow", there are no rules presented to use when you would not want to reenter your body. I would assume that you are forced to do so. It makes sense, since your astral projection would no longer be in the astral.

Comment: Historical note: In earlier editions of the game, if your astral body entered a plane other than the astral plane, a new body would be formed for you on that plane; if that body died, you'd return to your original one, still on the plane you started from. This made astral projection one of the safest ways to travel, since there were very few things that could kill you while using it.